# Link to an id in html django view with url ```view/<int:id>/<slug:slug>/```

Tags: django, href, django-urls

I have a view in django that views product details. In my urlpatterns list it's like the following.

```
urlpatterns = [
...
path('view/<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
...
]
```

Now I want to create a link of the following form [mysite.com/view/1/drone/#reviews](https://example.com//view/1/drone/#reviews). I tried this and it doesn't bring me to the reviews section. But for a normal url like the following it works with no problem.

```
urlpatterns = [
...
path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
...
]
```

Can someone help me what's the difference here? Because when it's like this I can access [mysite.com/#some_element](https://example.com/#some_element)

Comment: Is there are any errors shown?

Comment: The `#...` is the *fragment*. This is *never* send to the server. You will need CSS/JavaScript to handle it accordingly.

Comment: I am now working with Javascript since I couldn't find any other way. Thank you.

Comment: I will just use regex